# How to prove an address is existed on my node?

Tags: parity, addresses

I want to get whether an address is exited on my node in the Parity. But I just find the `parity_allAccountsInfo`. It will return all accounts. I don't need too much information. And it will take me a lot of time to deal with this information to find out whether this address is existed.

So I want to know is there any way to prove it with a simple way? Thanks a lot~ :)

Comment: Hi there. Your question is a bit ambiguous :-) Do you mean you want to check if an account with a specific address exists _on your node_? Or do you mean that you want to use your node to check if a specific address exists on the entire network?

Comment: Just on my node. I have changed my question. Thank you your advice. :)

Comment: I've not worked on parity, but if there is a function to check account balance in parity then pass the account address to that function as an argument. if that throws an error then it means the account doesn't exist otherwise it will give you some value. In geth, the command to check balance is eth.getBalance("account address")

Comment: Oh! It's a good idea! Thanks a lot! I think it will work successfully. :)

Comment: Hi @YangYifei. Did you mange to solve your issue? If so, could you add an answer explaining what you did? :-)